# How can I pass array values to a property of Object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I have two arrays(word and translatedWord). They contain words(word array contains words in english and translatedWord contains the same words but in another language ). I want to create an array of objects, each object to have the properties value, translation and id. I solved how I can create an object with the translatedWord properties, but I don't know how can I add the word values.
I want something like:

```
[
   {
      value:word[0],
      translation:translatedWord[0]
   },
   {
      value:word[1],
      translation:translatedWord[1]
   }
]
```

**Arrays:**

```
const word=['table','chair','bottle']
const translatedWord=['masa','scaun','sticla']
```

**My object**

```
 const [object, setObject]=React.useState({
    value:'',
    translation:'',
    id: nanoid(),
    isFavorite:false
  })
```

My idea is to create two functions like this:

**Function for populate the object with translated property:**

```
 function addTranslateToObject(){
    setObject(prevValue=>translatedWord.map(data=>({
       ...prevValue,
       translation:data
    })))
```

**Function for populate the object with value property:**

```
function addValue(){
    setObject(prevValue=>prevValue.map(data=>(
      {
      ...data,
      value:word[index]   //the problem is: I don't know how to increment the index value
    }))
    )
  }
```

Comment: How about this .
```setObject(prevValue=>prevValue.map((data,index)=>(
      {
      ...data,
      value:word[index] 
    }))
    )```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my POV, the `useState` looks like this:

```js
const [object, setObject] = React.useState([])
```

While in the `setObject`, I'd pass in the `words` array ( that contains the values) mapped into a new array with the desired object.

```js
setObject(words.map((word, index) => {
    return {
       id: index, 
       value: word,
       translation: translatedWord[index],
       isFavorite: false 
    }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a function that parses the arrays and then you set the returned values to the object.

I have provided you the solution here

```js
const foo = ['bar', 'foobar'];
const translFoo = ['translBar', 'translFoobar'];


const baz = (arr1, arr2) => {
    return arr1.map((data, index) => {
    return {
    value: `${data}[${index}]`,
    translation: `${arr2[index]}[${index}]`
    }
  })
 }

const obj = baz(foo, translFoo)

console.log(obj)
```

Only problem is with this, arrays need to be same length.